# Best approach to calculate overlap between two boxes

Tags: php, math

I need to calculate how many the overlap of the actual box is against the expected box. I have the following information:

```
{
 "expectedBox": {
   "height": 66,
   "length": 60,
   "width": 69,
   "xAxis": 159,
   "yAxis": 24,
   "zAxis": 147
 },
 "actualBox": {
   "height": 66,
   "length": 60,
   "width": 69,
   "xAxis": 159,
   "yAxis": 24,
   "zAxis": 147
  }
}
```

1. I need a percentage of the part from the actual box that is **inside** the expected box.
2. And I need a percentage of the part from the actual box that is **outside** the expected box.

Currently I have the following:

```
$obj1 = new StdClass;
$obj1->height = 66;
$obj1->length = 60;
$obj1->width = 69;
$obj1->xAxis = 159;
$obj1->yAxis = 24;
$obj1->zAxis = 147;

$obj2 = new StdClass;
$obj2->height = 68;
$obj2->length = 67;
$obj2->width = 69;
$obj2->xAxis = 260;
$obj2->yAxis = 23;
$obj2->zAxis = 142;

echo "<strong>RESULT</strong>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r(recursive_array_diff(json_decode(json_encode($obj1), true), 
json_decode(json_encode($obj2), true)));
echo "</pre>";

echo "<strong>EXPECTED</strong>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r((array)$obj1);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<strong>ACTUAL</strong>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r((array)$obj2);
echo "</pre>";

function recursive_array_diff($a1, $a2) {

    $r = new StdClass;
    $r->diff = new StdClass;
    $r->diff->data = array();
    $r->diff->expected = new StdClass;
    $r->diff->actual = new StdClass;

    // Expected box - Calculate volume length, width, height
    $r->diff->expected->volume = ($a1['length'] * $a1['width'] * $a1['height']);

    // Actual box - Calculate volume length, width, height
    $r->diff->actual->volume = ($a2['length'] * $a2['width'] * $a2['height']);

    // Expected box/Actual box - Calculate difference between values length, width, height, xAxis, yAxis, zAxis.
    foreach ($a1 as $k => $v) {
        if (array_key_exists($k, $a2)) {
            $r->diff->data[$k] = abs($v - $a2[$k]);
        } else {
            $r->diff->data[$k] = null;
        }
    }

    $r->diff->actual->volumeAtXyzExpected = abs($a2['length'] - $a1['zAxis']) * abs($a2['width'] - $a1['zAxis']) * abs($a2['height'] - $a1['yAxis']);
    $r->diff->actual->percentageOutsideExpected = (abs($r->diff->expected->volume - ($r->diff->actual->volume - $r->diff->actual->volumeAtXyzExpected)) / ($r->diff->expected->volume) *100);

    return json_encode($r,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Does that approach work?

Comment: Take a look here: http://paulbourke.net/fractals/randomtile/index.html

Comment: You are talking about axis aligned boxes? What do the parameters `xAxis`, `yAxis`, `zAxis` mean? The differences `$a2['length'] - $a1['zAxis']`, ... look weird. What should the (geometric) meaning of these expressions be?